# Can a 1-dimensional matrix be lower triangular?

Tags: matrices

If we have a 1-dimensional matrix say (2), is it lower or upper triangular?

Comment: Only square matrices can be lower/upper triangular.

Comment: Isn't a 1 dimensional matrix a square matrix? @Element118

Comment: @Element118: I see no reason a nonsquare matrix can't be triangular. All matrices have a main diagonal, regardless of dimensions, and "upper (lower) triangular" just means everything below (above) the diagonal is zero.

Comment: @MPW Does a 2x1 have a diagonal ?

Comment: @Dezmondeo: Yes. The diagonal elements of *any* matrix are the elements $a_{i,j}$ for which $i=j$. Since the number of rows may not be equal to the number of columns, the number of diagonal elements will be the smaller of those. In your case, the diagonal element is only $a_{1,1}$. That is, if the $2\times 1$ matrix is $(a,b)^T$, then only $a$ is on the diagonal.

Comment: @MPW thank you i did not know that

Comment: This is just my definition. Others may require squareness before any of these terms apply. So you could *define* it however you like. Intuitively, a "diagonal" should go from one corner to another, but this is a generalization that is convenient. +1 for your learning experience ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is both. It is also diagonal. But it isn't "strictly upper triangular" or "strictly lower triangular" (those require $0$s on the diagonal).